# What is the process of making a Javascript Slider/Scroller?

Tags: javascript, slider, scroller

OK I don't know if this is a proper question for this site or not but hopefully it is. I have been trying for the life of me to learn (understand) the process of being able to create an element slider. For example, If i had 10 images in a box where only 2 would display at a time, I want to be able to either click and drag the images to slide them, or be able to create an element and click and drag that to slide the images over. I want to know how to be able to click an image/element and drag it to the left or right, or up/down, and have it slide the images left or right as I do it. Now the reason I am asking on here is because I DO NOT want to have to use a plug in if I don't have to. I am trying to learn how to do it myself, not take someones shortcut and just apply that. Im trying to learn everything from the ground up, using as little shortcuts as possible. Thanks ahead of time for any answers. I would really really appreciate some help on this subject. I can't find anything simple enough to be able to break down and understand yet. And I know how overflow works, Im not talking about that type of scrolling. Same effect, just want to create my own.

Comment: You may be interested in the _MDN_ pages on _drag and drop_ [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop). If that's not what you meant by click and drag, then it's the _mousedown, mousemove_ and _mouseup_ events you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, ill check it out. Im looking for help with being able to click and drag one element, to move some other elements. Something to that effect.

Comment: Drag and drop works like this: mousedown (not click) on an element that triggers a setInterval, this interval monitors the mouse position and the position of the element, changing the position of the element periodically so that it looks like you're dragging it. Mouseup stops dragging. Obviously it's a little more complicated, you can try reverse engineering already existing plugins